# Using a range in a groovy case statement

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I'm writing a Jenkins pipeline, and I'd like to use a groovy switch statement to match on a range on int values so I don't have to write a case for each number in the range. Not used to groovy, so apologies if this is a simple question. For example (not working):

```
switch (diskuse) {
   case 1-5: //this doesn't work
     println('disk use is under 50')
     break

   case [5-9]: //this also doesn't work
     println('disk use is OVER 50!')
     break

   default: //the switch always hits this case
     println('no disk use info available')
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct range literal looks like `1..5` in Groovy. 
Your switch op shall look like so:

```
switch (diskuse) {
   case 1..5: //inclusive range
     println('disk use is under 50')
     break

   case 5..<9: //exclusive range, 9 is exluded
     println('disk use is OVER 50!')
     break

   default:
     println('no disk use info available')
}
```